# How to keep session value when I reload HAProxy Config?

Tags: haproxy

My HAproxy is work for Terminal Server.

We have more then 7x VM (Terminal Server) for user.

My problem is that I usually can see Haproxy stats at it's web GUI, but when some VM have Problem,I need to disable that or some place over loading ,

I had to change my config and had to restart my Haproxy Service afterwards. However I'm unable to allow on-line user to disconnect. I've found a way to use this script. It can let Haproxy to reload config and not let user disconnect.

But when I reload config,the current session at GUI is set to "zero" and the next user that logs in, would login at the first server.

That's causing a load balance problem. How can I reload my Haproxy config and not let session to zero?

```
/usr/sbin/haproxy -D -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid)
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far and the exact issue you're seeing?

Comment: Hi,I have no idea how to do.
My point is try to save session data,when I restart service,the data could be input to HAProxy.

Comment: Are you asking about haproxy server state https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#3.1-server-state-file?

Comment: example: if i have 100 users & 01~10 terminal servers,the ideal loadbalance is avg 20 for each vm,and if in the short time,if 06~09 have some problem,I need to disable login,so I must to edit my haproxy config and reload or restart it.
but the loadbalance will be have problem when I restart  HAProxy service,right? It would start from 1→2→3 ,it would let sever not balance when I restart the HAProxy.

Comment: Is it possible to maintain the queue while restarting HAProxy? When I reload or restart HAProxy Service,the stat will start from zero,it would clean all my session data,even I can keep session not disconnect use -sf. My lodbalance method is least connect,so if I restart or reload the service too many times,the loadbalance would had some problem.